# Как вместо POST запроса отправить Ajax при нажатии на button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма с `<button type="submit" class="btn-main">` как отправлять ajax при ее нажатии?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('form.main button.btn-main').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some-url/',
        data: $('form.main').serialize(),
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

См. другие параметры по [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) и по [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Answer (score 1):

Может вам интересно как отправить именно по клику, не отлавливая сам сабмит формы.

```
<button onClick='func()' class="btn-main">

var func = function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/some-url/',
                data: 'data',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

`button type="submit"` у вас вызовет событие сабмита формы, поэтому правильнее использовать именно его.

```
$(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```